# Rust macro strange error

Tags: rust

I'm working through rust's macro system attempting to make an ORM wrapper over Diesel.  Working through the belongs to, I found that rust is sending a rather unexpected error.  Please consider the following code:

```
macro_rules! klass {
    (
        $name:ident,
        fields => ($(
            $field:ident : $type:ty = $default:expr,
        )*),
        belongs_to => ($(
            $belong_field:ident : $temp:ty [ $key:expr ],
        )*)
    ) => {
        struct $name {
            $( $field: $type, )*
        }
        impl Default for $name {
            fn default() -> $name {
                $name {
                    $(
                        $field : $default,
                    )*
                }
            }
        }
        impl $name {
            $(
                fn $belong_field(&self) -> $temp {
                    let key = $key;
                    $temp { ..Default::default() }
                }
            )*
        }
    }
}

klass! ( Neat,
        fields => (
            id: i32 = 0,
            name: String = String::from(""),
        ),
        belongs_to => ()
    );

klass!( Bob,
    fields => (
        id: i32 = 0,
        neat_id: i32 = 0,
    ),
    belongs_to => (
        neat: Neat [ "neat_id" ],
    )
);

fn main()
{
    let b = Bob { ..Default::default() };
    let mut n = b.neat();
}
```

This code will yield the following result:

```
error: expected expression, found `Neat`
  --> macro.rs:27:31
   |
27 |                       $temp { ..Default::default() }
   |
```

Why does rust say it wants an expression instead of Neat?  I can change this code to the following and everything in this example compiles and runs:

```
Neat { ..Default::default() }
```

Is this a compiler error given when "Neat" is inserted the program runs as expected?  Thanks, apologizes for this mostly being code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$temp` occurs in different contexts in macro expansion. As a type in `fn $belong_field(&self) -> $temp` and as a structure constructor in `$temp { ..Default::default() }`.

You've marked `$temp` as a type, it prevents second usage.

Replacing the line

```
$belong_field:ident : $temp:ty [ $key:expr ],
```

with

```
$belong_field:ident : $temp:ident [ $key:expr ],
```

allows the code to compile.